# Does being an Irish person born in the UK make me a previous British citizen?

Tags: visas, paperwork, uk-citizens, irish-citizens

I am an Irish citizen born in the UK, as far as I can tell I've not "applied" for British citizenship. I'm currently applying for visas and many of them are asking for previous citizenship. Was I previously a British citizen?

Comment: Have you done this: https://www.gov.uk/check-british-citizen/ ?

Comment: @CMaster just did it and this was the result

You might not be a British citizen if both the following apply:
you were born before 1 July 2006
your parents weren’t married when you were born (and aren’t married now)
You’re a British citizen if this doesn’t apply to you. You don’t need to register or naturalise, and you can live in the UK and get a British passport.

---

I was born in 1992 to two married Irish Citizens, does this mean I've never had British citzenship?

Comment: My reading of that is that you are a British Citizen (it says you wouldn't be if your parents were unmarried, but they were, so you are. This seems to be provided that your parents were "settled" in the UK - ie living there and having leave to remain as long as they wanted. See https://www.gov.uk/types-of-british-nationality/british-citizenship

Comment: @CMaster the Ireland Act 1949 says that all Irish residents in the UK will be  automatically treated as permanently settled. So if the OP was born in the UK to those parents he is a dual national. There's no 'previously' about it.

Comment: The gov.uk site does not give a definition of "settled". Irish citizens have a de-facto right to abode in the United Kingdom. Neither of them were/are British citizens so the only point left is if they were "settled" Do you know what this term means?

Comment: I know what it means. For an Irish national it means they live here. Read the act for more info.

Comment: @GayotFow I just read the act there, so I have dual nationality. If i put on my visa that I am an Irish national, must I then also declare that I was previously British as I was born there?

Comment: No, you are not 'previously' British. You are a dual now. Unless you have formally renounced you will always be British. You're dual, you need to come to terms with it and put it down on the form.

Comment: If in doubt apply as an Irish citizen? If you have an Irish passport and not a British passport this would be the easiest way to apply for multiple visas without much hassle.

Comment: I've never owned a British passport, and the application doesn't allow me to select British. I'll simply put down Irish and hope for the best. Thank you all for the help.

Comment: In the future, get a British passport and then travel on the one that provides the most flexibility. The British passport may be more helpful in the Commonwealth etc etc

Comment: You can try to apply for a British passport as a final test :)

Comment: Why does the application not allow you to choose British?  Are you for some reason applying for a UK visa?

Comment: This appears to be a question about citizenship laws, not about travel.

Answer (score 18):

[According to Gov UK](https://www.gov.uk/types-of-british-nationality/british-citizenship), a person born in the UK to "settled" parents will be a British Citizen.

> If you were born on or after 1 January 1983, you’ll be a British citizen if your mother or father was either:
>
> - a British citizen when you were born
> - ‘settled’ in the UK when you were born

You can also [use a quick quiz](https://www.gov.uk/check-british-citizen/) on the site to determine if you are a british Citizen.

According to user Gayot Fow, the Ireland Act 1949 states that Irish citizens living in the Uk are treated as settled (i.e., permanent residents).

Based on this, you were not previously a British citizen, **because you are presently a British Citizen**. You hold two nationalities, until the point that you give one of them up. Any questions that ask about additional nationalities, you should mention this.

Comment: Asserting British citizenship can come with future obligations or difficulties that are hard to predict today. I would be cautious about advising people to assert a citizenship that they have never exercised before, unless they have a clear reason to do so. It is true that the citizenship is there regardless, but in some circumstances what matters is whether the holder ever officially acknowledged it.